# Best Way to collect thread stuck from weblogic Server

Tags: python, api, weblogic, weblogic12c

I need to collect different informations about weblogic servers in a production environnnement . I am currently using the restful management services api to collect a lot informations like health and status .
But this api can't give me informations like threadstuck.

My Question is What is the best way to collect threadstuck using python or another langage.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i think is to use JMX and runtime mbeans. The ThreadPoolRuntimeMBean is the entry point to get all exexute threads and then get their state. You will also get the information if the thread is hogging or stuck. Have a look to the [mbean reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/wlsmbeanref/core/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty hard. If you are on WLS 11g, you'll need to run through all of the work manager runtimes for each application. If your WLS is a 12c environment every server runtime has a ThreadPoolRuntime which has a "stuckthreadcount" attribute.

Here's a WLS 12c wlst example that prints the number of stuck threads per server:

```
## Prevent printing WLST verbose output to the screen
redirect('/dev/null','false')

## Insert your own password here
connect("weblogic", <your password>, "t3://localhost:7001")

domainRuntime()
servers = ls('/ServerRuntimes','true','c')
result = dict()
for server in servers:
    cd('/ServerRuntimes/' + server + '/ThreadPoolRuntime/ThreadPoolRuntime')
    result[server] = get('StuckThreadCount')

## Reenable printing output
redirect('/dev/null','true')
for key in result:
        print(key + " has "  + str(result[key]) + " stuck threads.")
```